# split an enumerated text list into multiple columns

Tags: python

I have a dataframe column which is a an enumerated list of items and I'm trying to split them into multiple columns.
for example

dataframe column that looks like this:

| ID | ITEMS |
| --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 1. Fruit 12 oranges 2. vegetables 7 carrot 3. NFL 246 SHIRTS |
| ID_2 | 1. Rock 2000 tons 2. PAPER 7 Notebook 3. Scissors 246 pairs |

the preferred result is something like this:

| ID | Fruit | vegetables | NFL | Rock | PAPER | Scissors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_1 | 12 oranges | 7 carrot | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ID_2 | 0 | 0 | 246 SHIRTS | 2000 tons | 7 Notebook | 246 pairs |

Also the number of the items varies from row to another [2-7]
I'm trying to use str.extract

```
 df['ITEMS'].str.extract('(\d\.+)', flags=re.M, expand=True)
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Seems you forgot to post your code? There are a few edge cases here that need to be addressed as well.

Comment: I've added the code, what are the edge cases ?

Comment: @AmrAlwakeal This code isn't enough. put all of it from scratch. I mean from where you create Dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

this codes works with me

```
df.str.split(pat="\d\.\s", expand=True)
```

this one breaks it down separating the numbers and the rest of the text

Comment: this line of code doesn't work for me. `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'` I guess you mean `df['ITEMS']` but still, the output i get is this: `0 1 2 3
ID_1  Fruit 12 oranges vegetables 7 carrot NFL 246 SHIRTS
ID_2  Rock 2000 tons PAPER 7 Notebook Scissors 246 pairs` You have the name for your columns and its values still in one cell...