# How can I avoid superfluous leading whitespace when splitting a string with RegEx pattern with words and numbers?

Tags: python, regex, split, python-re

My question came along when trying to help in this post: [split an enumerated text list into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71353971/split-an-enumerated-text-list-into-multiple-columns#71353971)

I'm searching for a Regex pattern which splits this string at `1.`, `2.` and `3.` or in general: split after a digit (or more if the list would be longer) followed by a dot. Problem is that there are more numbers in the string which are needed.

```
test_string = '1. Fruit 12 oranges 2. vegetables 7 carrot 3. NFL 246 SHIRTS'
```

With this pattern I managed to do so, but I got an empty string at the start and didn't know how to change that.

```
l1 = re.split(r"\s?\d{1,2}\.", test_string)

# Output l1:
['', ' Fruit 12 oranges', ' vegetables 7 carrot', ' NFL 246 SHIRTS']
```

So I changed from "split it" to "search something that finds the pattern":

```
l2 = re.findall(r"(?:^|(?<=\d\.))([\sa-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\d\.|$)", pattern)

# Output l2:
[' Fruit 12 oranges ', ' vegetables 7 carrot ', ' NFL 246 SHIRTS']
```

It is really close to be fine with it, just the trailing whitespace at the beginning of every element in the list.

What would be a good and efficient approach for my task? Stick with the splitting with `re.split()` or building a pattern and use `re.findall()`? Is my pattern good like I have done it or is it way too complicated?

Comment: You get a leading `''` because the string starts with a delimiter (so what appears before the first one is an empty string).

Comment: I figured out why there is an empty string, I just didn't know how to avoid that :D

Comment: If that's the only problem, just remove it.

Comment: True. That would be the easiest way. As you may can see my question isn't from a personal project where I just need a solution, I want to get a better understanding of regular expressions, and yeah....I just want to find a way where this is right in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just adding twice `(?:\s)` to your expression:

```
re.findall(r"(?:^|(?<=\d\.))(?:\s)([\sa-zA-Z0-9]+)(?:\s\d\.|$)", test_string)
```

The output is: `['Fruit 12 oranges', 'vegetables 7 carrot', 'NFL 246 SHIRTS']`

Comment: thanks! I added and deleted `\s` on different places but I guess I didn't try out the right one :P In total you agree with my approach? using Lookahead and Lookbehind to get everything in between ?

Comment: I didn't find a better approach but maybe there is! About the empty string given by split, it seems inevitable according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30933216/split-by-regex-without-resulting-empty-strings-in-python)

Comment: Note that `(?:\s)` = `\s`, there is no need in the redundant non-capturing group. It is only necessary when you need to quantify a group of patterns or use alternation.

Comment: @rehaqds nice post, thanks for that. It does make a bit more sense now to me !

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew also checked that one in my code. thanks for pointing that out.